# Updating RadGrid after every 5 secs

Tags: asp.net, telerik, updatepanel, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid inside a Update Panel. I want to update the grid after every five seconds.

My code for Grid is here

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ViewAllRequestPanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="loader" class="loadingpanel">
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="ViewAllRequestPanel">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <image src="../../Images/Loading.gif" class="InProgressImg" />
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </div>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" UpdateInitiatorPanelsOnly="true">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="GridViewAllRequests">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GridViewAllRequests" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" />
```

I have added a trigger for updating update panel asynchronously.

```
</asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Panel ID="TimerPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Timer ID="UpdateGridRequestsTimer" runat="server" Interval="8000" OnTick="Timer_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </asp:Panel>
```

C# code is as follows :

```
public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewAllRequests.Rebind();
    }
```

The issue is that full page is refreshing after some time.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you are setting your trigger on the update panel.  So the timer is doing a full post-back.  Try setting it like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ViewAllRequestPanel">
 <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="UpdateGridRequestsTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
```

Comment: I am getting Sys.InvalidOperationException: A control is already associated with the element

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following for my grids.

First off, add a asp:Timer as follows. Mine updates every 60 seconds.

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="timerRefresh" 
Interval="60000" OnTick="timerRefresh_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Then add the code behind for the click hander.

```
protected void timerRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.Rebind();
}
```

Then use rad ajax to update just the grd.

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="timerRefresh">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grid" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Voila! You are done.